# Graph Editor - Moving keyframes in relative to the main coordinate axis, not to their own origin

Tags: animation, bones, graph-editor

I'm in the process of creating a walking animation.
I would like to raise the hands of the characters, keeping their existing movement.

Manipulating the torso works, but on the hands it is more complicated because any changes I make in Graph Editor are relative to the starting position of T.
So when I try to put my hands only upwards, they move diagonally, backwards also, as my character moves forward leaving the original position behind.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Using delta transforms may be the most straightforward way to deal with this issue. Read the answer to this question and see if it addresses your concern. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132826/delta-keyframes-how-to-use

Comment: When I change delta transform it moves whole character

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new bone in edit mode, add to the hand IK controller a Child of constraint pointing at the new bone, then use the new bone in pose mode to raise the hand.

When satisfied in pose mode you can select the hand IK bone, go to Pose menu > animation > Bake action, ticking all of its preferences, and bake the animation to make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use rotation (FK) not grabbing (IK) to manipulating hands,
how to do that - [Rotating arms in Rigify](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237020/rotating-arms-in-rigify/237398#237398)
As well in Graph Editor not change Location, change Quaternion Rotation